# SQL: Combining rows after pivoting

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

part of an SQL query I'm writing handles a generic metadata table. Thus I'm pivoting the needed elements to fit into the format I need them to be. I'm doing it with "case" and I'm not sure if that's the or a problem, but the result of this subquery comes in this format:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ DATA1 ║ DATA2 ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 1     ║ (NULL)║
║  1 ║(NULL) ║ 2     ║
║  1 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║ 
║  2 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║
║  2 ║ 2     ║ (NULL)║
║  3 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║
║  4 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Not the most beautiful output, but I thought I can fix it with "GROUP BY ID" to streamline the output. It's as following:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ DATA1 ║ DATA2 ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║ ?????
║  2 ║(NULL) ║   2   ║
║  3 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║ 
║  4 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Maybe my understanding of GROUP BY is fundamentally wrong, but I did not expect the result for ID 1. Now I'm looking for a way to combine the rows. It should look something like this:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ DATA1 ║ DATA2 ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║   1   ║   2   ║ 
║  2 ║(NULL) ║   2   ║
║  3 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║ 
║  4 ║(NULL) ║ (NULL)║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

So simply "adding" the rows together is sufficient, since for one ID there will never be two values in a single data column. So it'll always be "number + NULL". Is there a way to do this without much hassle? I feel like this shouldn't be to much of a problem, but I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: Show the faulting query. I suspect you're running MySQL without "only full group by" active, and hence it's letting you get away with some imprecise  construct like `select id, case when blah = 1 then blah2 end from t group by id` - by not forcing you to group or agg the case when, it's just picking some value (and picking a null) that doesn't align with your expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT ID, MAX(DATA1) AS DATA1, MAX(DATA2) AS DATA2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```